# Physically how measurement in quantum mechanics works and how the formula is deduced?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements

This question seems a little broad but in fact it is very specified.
I read a lot of webpages and papers and books about measurement in quantum computing.
But in my opinion, they are just like "go around in circles"
most of them just refer to those mathematical formulas.
What I want to figure out is a concrete examaple.
For example, I have a lab, and I want to measure a electron, and so I need to construct a Hamiltonian. There is a famous formulat about exeternal Magnetic field on spin of particle:
$-u B\cdot S$

The first question is: is the Hermitian matrix changed after measurement?
The schrodinger formula is: $ih\frac{d\psi}{dt}=H\psi $
after measurement, it collapse, so what the H looks like after collapse? does it change? or just keep the same.

since measurement change the state. but state is also governed by shrodinger equation,so does that mean the shrodinger equation not works while in measuring, or it still works but it changed at the same time, but we can see the only variable parameter in shroidnger equation is the 'H'.

the second question is: where the measurement matrix comes from? or how the measurement operator corrseponding to physical obeservables?
measure can be represented as an operator, or matrix, but it must have a source, right? If not, how do you get the formula?
the papers often says:" there is correspondence bettwen the physical observable and the operator and then it list the matrix"
so could you give an example(e.g. in the context of spin of electron under magnetic field), how they are corresponded and where the $-uB\cdot S$ comes from?

the third question is why operators can be represented as matrix and at the same time derivates?
I saw some book write operators as a derivate, but sometimes it becomes a matrix. what is the relation between the derivate representation and matrix represention of a measurement operaotr?

I am studying quantum computing and I can understand each aspect except one conception: the measurement, definitely I understand those mathematical formulas, but I don't know how they comes from, I just want to a deduction of the measurement and how it affect the wave-function.
Another question is: can we know exactly what the wave function looks like after it collapse? is a formula which shows how exactly the wave function collpase?if so, how to deduce them?

Comment: It has been a long time since the majority of physicists subscribed to the view that we are special beings who can transcend quantum mechanics by making wavefunctions collapse. You should read about entanglement and decoherence.

Comment: This site has a one-question-per-post policy. You’ve asked fourteen, so your post will probably be closed unless you edit it.

Comment: Are you studying quantum computing without having first studied ordinary quantum mechanics? (It seems so from your questions.) For example, have you ever learned about the 1-dimensional particle-in-a-box?

Comment: Have you learned the [postulates of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Postulates_of_quantum_mechanics)? Note that there s a section called “Effect of measurement on the state”.

Comment: If you haven't already. I suggest you read the Wikipedia articles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_mechanics and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation. They are very informative.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Yes, we can all count several question marks in the post - but the questions are all related and have a straightforward answer.

Comment: @gandalf61 It is also about the quality of the post itself. OP should try to formulate precisely what they want to know, in a concise way. Despite that, I would disagree. OP asks several questions; yes, they are somehow related, but they can be asked in several posts. Also, they are not totally clear and some are very broad. But I would instead suggest to OP, as others have pointed out, to go back to a good textbook or so and learn the axioms of QM, and practice with some examples first.

Comment: @Ghoster yes, I am studying quantum computing without quantum mechanics, do you have any good mechanics book to recommend? I hope just to help me understand some basic concept related to quantum computing, not too deep.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the Hamiltonian will not change during the whole process. You can imagine that measurement is actually to perform a projective operator $P_m$ on the current state $|\psi\rangle$ after which the state become $P_m|\psi\rangle/\sqrt{\langle\psi|P_m|\psi\rangle}$ and all of these happen at a sudden. To know $\langle\psi|M|\psi\rangle$ we have to perform thousands of measurement on the same state and calculate their average. (That's enough for calculation. Measurement in quantum mechanics is a very profound topic. Many famous physicists have their own understanding. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics for more discussion.)

The general formulation of (projective) measurement is described by an observable $M$, a Hermitian operator on the state space of the system being observed. The observable has a spectral decomposition,
$$M = \sum_m m P_m$$
where $P_m$ is the projector onto the eigenspace of M with eigenvalue $m$.

So $\langle\psi|M|\psi\rangle = \sum_m m\langle \psi|P_m|\psi\rangle$ where $\langle\psi|P_m|\psi\rangle = p(m)$ is the probability that the outcome is $m$ in one measurement.

For the second question, the answer is quite simple. The easiest way to construct an observable is to calculate its matrix form in the energy eigenbasis. Generally, given a Hamiltonian, we can get its eigenstates $|E_i\rangle$ where $E_i$ denotes the eigen energy. And now we can calculate the observable matrix in the energy eigenbasis representation, i.e., $M_{ij} = \langle E_i|M|E_j\rangle$. (To calculate this, you have to know how the operator M acts on the state $|E_j\rangle$.)

The Hamiltonian $H=-uB\cdot S$ comes from that particles with spin in magnetic field will obtain a magnetic moment $\mu$ and magnetic moment in an externally produced magnetic field leads to a potential energy $U=-\mu\cdot B$. Quantum mechanically, we just replace the classical $\mu$ with the spin operator vector $S=(S_x, S_y, S_z)$ because generally $\mu\propto S$.

For simplicity, let's set the magnetic field $B=(0, 0, B_z)$, then the Hamiltonian will be $H=-uB_zS_z=c\sigma_z$.(The coefficient $-uB_z/2$ is unimportant here, so we set $B_z$ properly such that $c=1$ for simplicity.) In quantum mechanics, we know that $\sigma_z$ has two eigenstates denoted $|\uparrow\rangle$ and $|\downarrow\rangle$ with corresponding eigenvalue +1, -1. So the matrix form of $\sigma_z$ in this basis is
\begin{align}
\sigma_z = |\uparrow\rangle\langle \uparrow|-|\downarrow\rangle\langle\downarrow|=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Suppose now we want to know the matrix form of observable $\sigma_x$ and currently we only know that $\sigma_x|\uparrow\rangle = |\downarrow\rangle$ and $\sigma_x|\downarrow\rangle = |\uparrow\rangle$, i.e., the physical meaning of $\sigma_x$ is to flip the spin. However, that's enough to calculate the $\sigma_x$ matrix. By simple calculation we obtain
\begin{align}
\sigma_x = |\uparrow\rangle\langle \downarrow|+|\downarrow\rangle\langle\uparrow|=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

The third question has already been answered actually. For a given operator $\hat{A}$, we can always use a complete set of basis vector $\{|e_i\rangle\}$ to calculate its matrix form $A_{ij} = \langle e_i|\hat{A}|e_j\rangle$.  Other example is the momentum operator, in coordinate space it has the form $\hat{p} = -i\hbar\partial_x$ and you can formally write its matrix element as $p_{ij} = \langle x_i|(-i\hbar\partial_x)|x_j\rangle$ where $|x_i\rangle$ is the eigenstate of position operator $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{x}|x_i\rangle=x_i|x_i\rangle$.

Comment: The hamiltonian wouldn't change, that's a good answer. The third answer is also good, but how could you make sure that the derivative is linear? For second  question, your answer is also good but not what I expected since I have known them, what I want to figure out is where those formula comes from, is that a physical explanation about it.